# Differences among Weather Indicators

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, indicator, weather

To my knowledge there are two different weather applications with indicators for Unity -- what are the main differences and which one do you prefer over the other and why?

- [Weather Indicator](https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator)
- [MyWeather Indicator](https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator)

For instance do they support ...

- any number of cities/locations
- user chosen/defined services (yahoo, google, ...)
- show "felt temperature"
- show forecasts
- use popups/notify in addition to the indicator menu
- show pictograms or just text as indicator
- warn of rain or other weather changes (some defined time in advance)

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators 19 ppl like the 1st one and 8 the 2nd ;-) The "why" is rather subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer Weather Indicator (also known as indicator-weather) - not just because I'm one of the developers ;-)

Weather Indicator has a [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WeatherIndicator/) with information about its features.  It currently does all of your dot points except for "felt temperature" and "warn of rain" (unless you consider notifications as sufficent warning of weather changes).  You can install indicator-weather from the Ubuntu repositories, but I would strongly recommend getting the latest version from our [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~weather-indicator-team/+archive/ppa) ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa - it has lots of bug fixes.  The devs are currently working on a new version (foggy) that will be very pretty, and bring back "felt temperature" - with 4 different types!

My-Weather-Indicator currently does have "felt temperature" and moon phases (and dew point etc), but in my very biased opinion it is not as polished as indicator-weather.

Comment: I like Weather Indicator. However, one thing that I like about the My-Weather-Indicator is that I can use a Weather Underground API key and set my location to a PWS code which is within a few blocks from my house. This gives me extremely accurate data.