# My-Weather-Indicator alternatives?

Tags: unity, applet, weather

I've just removed the applet "My-Weather-Indicator"... this applet is really cool, but once or twice a day crashes on my ubuntu 12.10, so I decided to remove it.

Is there any valid alternative ? I need just a simple weather indicator applet

Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/44086/differences-among-weather-indicators?rq=1

Comment: Not so duplicate, since I'm looking for an alternative ..

Comment: ... and the weather indicator is not an alternative?

Comment: oh I tryied that but I still have problems with it. There are some known bugs :/

Comment: @fossfreedom weather indicator is no alternative because they stopped development (see http://launchpad.net/weather-indicator). I'm looking for an alternative to both these indicators too because both are kind of outdated.

Comment: Weather indicator is not an alternative because it does not allow the use of Weather Underground and, specifically, the use of a PWS code as a location if you have a Weather Underground API key. My-weather-indicator allows the use of a PWS from Weather Underground and so the accuracy of the temperature is usually within a radius of a few city blocks if you live in a good area.